# How to specify windows temp folder (%temp%) in filebeat.yml input paths

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

How to specify windows temp folder (%temp%) in filebeat.yml input paths since all my logs are written to appdata temp folder.

```
  paths:
    - %temp%\logs\*.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/using-environ-vars.html) can be used in filebeat.

paths:
    - ${temp}\logs*.log